# How can we handle time in SFML/C++?

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using SFML 2.1 with C++. I want to know that how can we handle our player's movement with a delay for example:

```
if(right-key-is-pressed)
{
    player.move(5, 0);
}
```

Now we want the player to move to 5 spaces but we want it to take 2 sec to do it.

How can we do it in SFML?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sf::clock in order to time your game.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1-fr/classsf_1_1Clock.php

Comment: I have read the documentation but I want to use it in `.move` function and I didn't understand how???

Comment: You're gonna have to increment his position based on time elapsed between frames.

Comment: @Faiz the pong example which comes with the library does that. Check the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main()
 {
 sf::Clock Clock;
 float LastTime = 0;

 //Main Game Loop
 while(Window.isOpen())
 {
 /* ... */
 float CurTime = Clock.restart().asSeconds();
 float FPS = 1.0 / CurTime;
 LastTime = CurTime;

 /*Then you could multiply the objects move axis speed by FPS*/
 Player->Shape.move(Vel.x * FPS, Vel.y * FPS);

 Window.clear();

 Window.display();
 }
 return 0
 }
```

Since CurTime = Clock.restart().asSeconds(); you may(more than likely) have to significantly increase the value of your Objects Velocity.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to introduce the concept of frame. Every second can have several frames, say 60. And each frame is a snapshot of objects state at a given time point in that second. You compute the states of objects in the new frame, and then render and show it on the screen at that time point, and continues to compute the frame.

In your example, say I can have 10 frames per second. The speed of the player is 5/2 unit/second. I'll compute the player state, and get player is at 0.25 at 0.1 seconds, 0.5 at 0.2 seconds, 0.75 at 0.3 seconds, and so on.